# Use JTable to save frontend-data

Tags: custom-component, jtable

I would like to save user-inputs (Form with multiple text-fields) from the frontend of my component using (admin-) `JTable`.
In this case I would like to save a new comment to the database.

I guess I could do it in the controller (overwrite the save-method) but I guess it would be better if I'd use the model and overwrite the save-method.

Is there any example how to do that?

Best regards :-)

Comment: The controller would be the proper place to override an existing action. Controllers are your setters, models are your getters if that helps you out in the future. You actions (db saves, redirects, etc.) should always take place in a controller.

Comment: So I would overwrite the save-Method in my controller and call the JTable, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain how joomla works imo.

Controllers are for creating / executing route and calling model for some work.

In controller you have method called `save` but it's preprocess `$_POST` aka `$data` and pass it to model, `$controller->getModel()->save()`.

For me it's better to call model and pass data and use multiple `JTable`, it's better for further use and lil' bit of joomla and `MVC` style.

So in model you can do:

```
$return = parent::save($data);
if($return) {
    // do something with other post data 
    // JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('jform', array(), 'array);
}

return $return; // ofc if code in statement was good too :-)
```

now do your work, i dare you! ]:->

Comment: Hello,

I'm working with your method. One question: In frontend I can not use JControllerForm - so I have to create a save-function which calls `$this->getModel()->save(); `. This works fine - but is it the best way? How can I automatically get $data without calling `Factory::getApplication()->input...`?

Comment: You need to extend administrator model and view and thats all.

Comment: Hi,

I extend my model from `JModelAdmin` now - but the views are always extended from `JViewLegacy`...? Well, the model seems to work but the controller does not accept a "save"-method if I do not declare it.

Comment: You need to extend `JControllerForm` controller in front and add `getModel` method into it.

Comment: Hello,

I added the getModel-Method to my JControllerForm and changed my model to extend from JModelAdmin. If I do not explicitly add the save-method to my controller and trigger `$this->getModel()->save($data);` the save-Method of the controller is not called.